# android:textisselectable not working in TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT window

Tags: android, android-view, textview, android-windowmanager

I am adding a `TextView` to a floating window which has attribute `android:textisselectable`.

```
mWindowManager.addView(textView, params);
```

Eveything is working fine except I cannot copy text on long press. The strange part is that it is working fine in Galaxy Tab but not on any other 5 inch phones I have.

Comment: textisselectable and scrollview wont work with popupWindow. Maybe its a bug in android

Comment: there is no `ScrollView` and as the question stated its working fine in tablets not in smaller 5 inch devices.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a version problem. The Galaxy Tab has a version more than Honeycomb whereas the 5 inches screen may be Honeycomb or lower.

Try this code:

```
TextView textView;
String stringToBeExtracted;
int startingIndex=textView.getSelectionStart();
int endingIndex=textView.getSelectionEnd();
stringToBeExtracted = stringYouExtracted.subString(startingIndex, endingIndex);
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    android.text.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.text.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    clipboard.setText(stringToBeExtracted);
} else {
    android.content.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.content.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    android.content.ClipData clip = android.content.ClipData.newPlainText("Text Copied", stringToBeExtracted);
            clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
}
```

Comment: I am using minimum API 14 in my app.